# Python Code keeps repeating the Input Value even when I try to "end" the code

Tags: python, input, infinite-loop

Here is my code, if you play it, then you should see what's wrong. I am not for sure how to end the code once the player dies or wins. Play till the ending and look at the code so you can understand what may be the issue.

Thanks so much, here is the code:

```
def start ():
    print ("Hello! Welcome to Prison Break!")
    print (""""You are a very infamous spy working with a foreign government in the US. You are always successful and have never been caught...until now.""")
    print ("You were captured by the FBI when you were walking down the street after a mission, and they jumped you.")
    print ("You don't know what is happening!")

    description_of_room()

def description_of_room ():
    print ("You wake up in a prison cell. Everything seems very old, dust lies on the ground, untouched for years.")
    print ("The room seems empty besides the cell bars, crumbling wall behind you, and a pile of rubble.")

    room_1()

def room_1 ():
    print("")
    prompt_0()

def prompt_0 ():
    prompt_0 = input("What do you do?.")
    try:
        if prompt_0 == "look":
            print("       ")
            description_of_room() # goes internally into room_1

        if prompt_0 == "cell bars":
            print("You examine the cell bars carefully.")
            print("The bars are very old, a wrench could be able to rip them open")
            room_1()

        if prompt_0 == "rubble":
            print("You closely examine the rubble. You see a metal rusty handle of something.")
            print("You pull it easily out of the rubble, its a old wrench, maybe it could be used on the cell bars.")
            options()

        elif prompt_0 == "wall":
            print("You examine the crumbling wall.")
            print("It is extremely old, it seems someone has cut away at it, making it delicate, a hammer could easily take care of it.")
            room_1()
        else:
            print("Please type in cell bars, wall, rubble, or look")
            room_1()
    except ValueError():
            print("ARE YOU CRAZY? DON'T TYPE NUMBERS! YOU'LL CRASH MY GAME!")
            print("           ")
            room_1()


    room_1()
    options()

def options():
    print()
    prompt_1()

def prompt_1():
    prompt_1 = input("Use wrench on bars or trade with Billy for a Hammer, who is next door.")

    try:
        if prompt_1 == "use wrench":
            print("The wrench will be able to break open the cell bars.")
            print("If you do it now you will be caught, you must wait till night.")
            escape_2_mor()


        if prompt_1 == "trade with billy":
            print("Billy is the common trader in the prison, he will take pretty much anything.")
            print("You give the rusty wrench to Billy and he gives you a decent small hammer, which can be used to smash the crumbly wall.")
            failure()

        elif prompt_1 == "Random":
            print("RANDOM")
            options()

        else:
            print("Type trade with billy or use on cell bars.")
            options()

    except ValueError():
        print("NO NUMBERS!")
        print("       ")
        options()



def escape_2_mor():
    print()
    prompt_3()

def prompt_3():
    prompt_3 = input("What do you do?")
    try:
        if prompt_3 == "wait":
            print("You wait till night.")
            escape_2_nih()


        elif prompt_3 == "use wrench":
            print("You were caught by the police, punishment is death.")
            print("You died, Game Over!")
            end()

        else:
            print("Type wait or use wrench")
            escape_2_mor()

    except ValueError():
        print("I SAID NO NUMBERS")
        print("     ")
        escape_2_mor()


def escape_2_nih():
    print()
    prompt_4()

def prompt_4():
    prompt_4 = input("It's midnight, you have the chance to use the wrench!")
    try:
        if prompt_4 == "use wrench":
            print("You slowly break the old bars, the noise echoing throughout the halls.")
            escape_2_nih_1()

        elif prompt_4 == "wait":
            print("You wait for no reason, it's morning again.")
            escape_2_mor()

        else:
            print("Type use wrench or wait")

    except ValueError:
        print("Why do I even try...")
        print("    ")
        escape_2_nih()


def escape_2_nih_1():
    print()
    prompt_5()

def prompt_5():

    prompt_5 = input("Your outside your cell bars, in a dark hallway, what do you do?")
    try:

        if prompt_5 == "crawl":
            print("You get on your knees quietly, making sure no one can see you.")
            print("You stick in the shadows and come across a guard.")
            print("You hit him on the head with the wrench, luckily he is wearing a helmet, so he is just knocked out.")
            escape_2_des

        elif prompt_5 == "run":
            print("You run quickly down the hallway, you see other cellmates sleeping.")
            print("You almost reach the metal door at the end of the hallway, but a guard turns and sees you.")
            print("He is so suprised that he fires his gun before you can attack him.")
            print("You fall to the ground, everything goes dark, you died.")
            end()

        else:
            print("Please type crawl or run")
            escape_2_nih_1()

    except ValueError:
        print("Just stop")
        escape_2_nih_1()

    escape_2_des()
def escape_2_des():
    print()
    prompt_6()
def prompt_6():
    prompt_6 = input("You press open the door and you see towering gates and a guard tower, what do you do?")

    try:

        if prompt_6 == "tower":
            print("You see the tower, and slowly approach it. You reach the tower and see its made out of stone that can be easily climbed.")
            print("You climb up the wall, and then reach the top. You can see that the tower is high enough to jump over the fence and escape.")
            print("You take a huge leap and fall to the ground, you look behind you and see the fence and the prison.")
            print("You have escaped the prison! You Win!")
            end()

        if prompt_6 == "fence":
            print("You slowly approach the fence and put your hand on it to start climbing.")
            print("You are quickly electrocuted by the electric fence, stopping your heart.")
            print("You've lost!")
            end()

        else:
            print("Type fence or tower")
            escape_2_des()

    except ValueError:
        print("Your annoying")
        escape_2_des()


def failure():
    print()
    prompt_7()
def prompt_7():
    prompt_7 = input("You can now break open the crumbled wall")

    try:

        if prompt_7 == "break wall":
            print("You hammer away at the wall, which is breaking down easily.")
            print("All the sudden a guard comes up from behind and stares down at you.")
            print("Hello Officer! How are you doing today?")
            print("Please come with me inmate.")
            print("He pulls you by the shoulders and walks you down into a different cell, a more clean and sturdy cell.")
            print("He pushes you in and locks the cell bars behind you, you have failed and will never get out.")
            end()

        if prompt_7 == "wait":
            print("You wait for no reason, good job!")
            failure()

        else:
            print("Type wait or break wall")

    except ValueError:
        print("Whatever")
        failure()
    end()
def end():
    print("Congrats you have either won or failed the game. I hope you enjoyed!")
    print("             ")
    print("Ignore the statement underneath, the code is being an idiot")



start()
```

It would be a huge help if anyone could help, thank you. I am not for sure if it's the input that is the issue or what, but it keeps repeating. You can use pycharm if you have it because that is what works for me, if it does not work in any of the other programs you may use to run python then just try to please use Pycharm because I know it works.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not the minimal code to exemplify the problem. Can you create a [MCVE] that still runs but shows less code, please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please cut the code down. If you want strangers over the internet to help you, do not increase their work by adding so many lines where people have to squint to find where exactly your problem lies.

Comment: Why should it behave differently if you have an infinite loop? When entering `room_1` you go to `prompt_0` and from any branch you go to `room_1`. Even when you have `prompt_0 == "look"`. You still go into another branches and appear into `else`

Comment: You use **consecutive** `if ... if ...`, change to `elif ...`. Think about @DmytroChasovskyi comment. Remove the `end()` in line *230*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `end` function doesn't actually stop the code execution.  what you need to do is this

```
import sys

#your code
#your code
#your code

def end():
    print("Congrats you have either won or failed the game. I hope you enjoyed!")
    print("             ")
    print("Ignore the statement underneath, the code is being an idiot")
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you haven’t added a loop into it limit the loop by the set amount.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).